# The app runs fine in a kitkat emulator but not on a kitkat device. It also run on a lollipop device but not on a kitkat device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

some messages in Logcat are:

1. Could not find class `android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable`, referenced from method `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`
2. `tid 22118: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)`

The app runs fine in a kitkat emulaor but not on a kikat device. It also run on a lollipop device but not on a kitkat device.

Answer (score 1):

`RippleDrawable` is introduced in API 21 and it is not backward compatible meaning the devices running on Android before Lollipop can not have `RippleDrawable.`

However there are certain library which can mimic the ripple effect quite excellently. Refer to this github project : https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable

Also i suggest you to refer Android Developer https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

If you don't wish to use library you can always check the device version and act accordingly.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

// pre-lollipop
}else {

//after lollipop.
}
```

or you can define the drawable sepeartely for prelollipop and above lollipop.

```
drawable-v21 is for lollipop and above lollipop.
drawable is for prelollipop.
```

use the same name of the drawable and pu it in according to the Android version.